# One line proof, convexity of a set

Tags: summation, convex-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a set, and we define $B$ to be the set of all convex combinations of elements of $A$.

By convex combination I mean $\sum_{i=1}^{p}t_ix_i$ where $x_i \in A$, $t_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^p t_i = 1$ for some $p$.

I want to understand this proof that $B$ is convex:

Take $x,y \in B, \lambda \in [0, 1]$:

$\displaystyle \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y = \lambda \sum_{i=1}^pt_ix_i + (1-\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^rs_iy_i = \sum_{i=1}^{p+r}\xi_iz_i$

Where $\xi_i = \lambda t_i + (1-\lambda)s_i, \xi_i \geq0, \sum_{i=1}^{p+r}\xi_i = 1$

I can't understand what $z_i$ is and why $z_i \in A$.

Comment: The $z_i$ are the sequence of all $x_i$ and $y_i$, with possible repetitions. For example, $z_i=x_i$, for $i=1,...,p$ and $z_i=y_{i-r}$, for $i=r+1,...,p+r$. But they are reusing $t_i$ and $s_i$ for a new pair of sequences when they write $\chi_i$. Re-define $t_i=$ (the original) $t_i$ for $i=1,2,...,r$ and $t_i=0$ for $i>r$, and re-define $s_i=0$ for $i=1,...,r$ and $s_i=$ (the original) $r_{i-r}$, for $i=r+1,...,p+r$.

Comment: Nicer would have been to say that both $x$ and $y$ are convex combinations $\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_ix_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_ix_i$ of the same set of points $x_1,...,x_n$ of $A$ by possibly putting some coefficients $t_i$ and $s_i$ equal to zero when the corresponding $x_i$ is not needed in the convex combination. Then $p=r=n$, one doesn't need a new variable $z_i$, and $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\lambda t_i+(1-\lambda)s_i]x_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sloppy.

Suppose $x= \sum_{i=1}^p t_i x_i$ and $y=\sum_{j=1}^r s_j y_j$ with $t,s$ satisfying the relevant constraints.

Let $z=(x_1,...,x_p,y_1,...,y_r)$,
$\bar{t} = (t_1,...,t_p,0,...,0)$ and $\bar{s} = (0,...,0,s_1,...,s_r)$, then we can write
$x=\sum_{k=1}^{p+r} \bar{t_k}z_k $, $y=\sum_{k=1}^{p+r} \bar{s_k}z_k $.

Then $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y = \sum_{k=1}^{p+r} (\lambda\bar{t_k} +(1-\lambda) \bar{s_k}) z_k $.

Letting $\xi=(t_1,...,t_p,s_1,...,s_r)$, we have $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y = \sum_{k=1}^{p+r} \xi_k z_k $.

It is straightforward to check that $\xi$ satisfies the summation and non negativity constraints.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Would have taken my a long time to understand what the poet meant on my own.